# Typescript infer function return property type from interface mapping argument property

Tags: typescript

I am writing a generic class to handle messaging between the browser and a web worker. Both sides create a class which can then send specifically defined messages and the other acknowledges the message, and filling in a returned result on a payload. This is all working perfectly, and I've got an interface mapping to handle sending messages.

The part I'm stuck on is inferring a return type based on the interface mapping as an argument to the function.

Below I have the playground link with the interfaces, class and implementation.

I'm basically trying to sort out the send function:

```
messages.send({ action: MessageAction.Init, data: { scripts: [] } }).then(data => {
  // need to infer the return type from the action.
  console.log(data);
});
```

Basically, from the playground, instead of returning void, I would need it to look up and infer that data is actually `AcknowledgeMessageData<InitReturn>` because the action property of the argument is 'init' (currently not generic) so the object would look like.

```
{
   isSuccess: true,
   result: {
      someRandomProperty: '',
      anotherProperty: 0
   }
}
```

And different actions would lead to different generic `result` properties.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECcFMGcFcBsAuB%20U0AWB7BATAdgOSKgBGkoAhngJ4A0psxFoA5pHpOAJYDGAUJAAeAB0zhiXPIk4AzCj3IBBHgGs8mAO7xIONgFkY0CmwAiFRMyHS8OaKABCFaJAPQjp8xQA8Ab1BdoAGVYHgU3AC5STExtKnpOcDFkSKo6CBgEFBSaUABfAD5QHz5QUsoeRC5MPEjXd0hlSuqAOmU1TW1dSABuPly%20PhA0TABbSCwNUA4dUERMNGFIHi4Zaln0cihEWHAOHFAANwp4WHIZMXXyeXatHTZWdk5eShJMA-JkT4ERMQkpWXk5AAknguIg6sZIGYLKArOxbA4nC5DJDod4-NAeNxhIhoJFoIhuHgWABtAC6eUKxTK5SaNVAELYjSqeGaILBvX631E4n8-3AcgUoHZiAASpBtrsiiVhmNRVQcKMAAqJRbiaj4wmSFi9UpUTCIDbgFWYNWIDVTWAjMjgTkDIQ84jsK0MlFMios6U0trqW5dUAAXlABGuBFoMtKIsDwckYIIfXtP155sWrrcqM80b8JIA0ny0-VmdUybU3VDPHoKMJhNrcxTciTGQ0PcXetzfnzpALAYjnE20V4ACpoqkR-w4SJ4K023VleR00vp9102elHCeSLDzx2viSLuC8j9itVmvEr1lRtlousn0dO6QEugW9%20-RltGr0CXpfNuls0GIR8RSPCwdwGMCBh4eAnDsJs7GpUBhG4I5pDQCxKh4cdowAWgARlnRCuGQ8gxm-Owgw4SZK2ELwp2tTh6BJAAxWA8BbPB6GY1i6TJfIAAoAEo21KYRYBIeBnicahWLQeFePXCxIgAeRGMEvGAih6AILgcAIfJ%20PPUoth2PApkgSYTRU5wvAOTBtL43ioGgGJ3noKAACslkQfSA1HGkaUNAJmhI%20poGaZxEF4gBqSLYOabSGMc5zIFcyAPIqMlBLHGlnHgGRmlEAkmzkzxMppXJSryAZhNE8SMOqXieGOeASGuSJioUgsMwsbzCgsgJIGs2ycD0gy-JyvLqmCyFo0k6TeMgd4pEXeoAFFFsQNS308EafNGvyyhWUB5vW5p5IoZp509ANrs65cWVaVRfU6Nh9Pg-b3vWQLqmfZ7IGO9hEFOkqPw%20mkjN2EH3q5UG5w0CgwU%200LqiKxr4Ga654hOs6Kv23IP2hsoCKI0Bvseu8ul4qa2EiH773U16srKHhqgJT9EvgFz0jSgDowC0KqZgZo2AigW4pwfiAEIhPew7eIl9n3lAAAfJXQHl1LPIZmHDIlYzIdKAn9r5oKy1CnBIG0aRKbLMXMsZ0pZdFs64qCEIwmgLXtYVv6neB%2028lheBnD2973M863vyBixmgSC5PlAAADRQTJYm4TNj8ASdCHYoBwBOcb8-oyqqsohkNTZdalI4TnII1yA0bB4H2MhQDHInzCuaApLqvAUaalrVDas7lq6igetAPqrNT308HyegBZHjxupD0pLf8V3QkMSJXhiSAqGjOQg56f218czJsmofXQDXjOL%20lo3wDWN7QbPpAZrhhHUfR1QI-qAuPoCMETebhebgFOFfXIoBGqIB4OgI6QgFA4hZBfT2MMM7RgQZAJB1RkAm2-KAeOScU54DTrCcAiRM6YGzuQnQCcr40kAW7QwB9jjOAgaAGQkgmpP39jSZmeBWaOVEAIyANMyYvmRN%20NEWZeEywnKAUW8VZH7UutUReP57q0y6OGbWflh4r10evIB7tlGF1MXjEuMNZavy8gYj6QiWaQCjudGx0YbH0LKIbUGssM6oMMQ4kRziY7kIuEGDOHiDaWNBuNfKmBCplgcjAYRzh-6eLHP0Lk4EwL8NZgLMiplKKmwEm2PJYVZJ%20FUfSJs14-xgnoPojEWIuA4jxJ%20eseR%20LNHLngdqzBdrwSGNMfYcw%20QyE4JcdIkoTIpjOIkEYEzKnNBlDk3ezR4CYBYL0zK5USmm2aPVWaGEBaBl8mgDQYJYFHVFpUvxjVg7VLYg9G4v1wiMyGA3cAKhoCM19tHRhwDoCQxIFACgKgPx3MPFeR5IpXn7XeWIL5PybbO0xNiXEQKQVgplBkzKQA)

Could not figure out how to get the infer to happen based on property off argument, and apply it to the property of the return value.

Edit: added minimal reproduction

```
enum Action {
    Ack = 'ack',
    Init = 'init'
}

interface BaseMessage {
    action: Action;
}

interface AckBaseMessage extends BaseMessage {
    action: Action.Ack;
}

interface InitBaseMessage extends BaseMessage {
    action: Action.Init;
}

interface MessageDataMapping {
    [Action.Ack]: AckBaseMessage;
    [Action.Init]: InitBaseMessage;
}

export type Message = { [K in Action]: MessageDataMapping[K] }[Action];

async function send(payload: Message) {
    return thisWouldBeReturnedFromWebWorker(payload);
}

async function thisWouldBeReturnedFromWebWorker(payload: Message): Promise<any> {
    if (payload.action === Action.Init) {
        return {
            action: Action.Init,
            result: {
                somePropertiesHere: true
            }
        };
    }

    return { action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } }
}

send({ action: Action.Init }).then(response => {
    // this should be infered, because action: Action.Init was passed into the send function
    response.result.somePropertiesHere

    // this should only be inferred if the action was Action.Ack
    response.result.isSuccess
});
```

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible. You are trying to infer the generic type based on the response or not? If this is my correct understanding then I can ellaborate more

Comment: @WouterVandenputte no, I'm trying to infer the generic type of the response based on the input argument to the send function.

`send({ action: 'init' })`

so from action: 'init', infer what the return of the function should be

Comment: I'm sure it's at least possible to make the types work the way you want (although the implementation might need type assertions), but the example is confusing me.  Please [edit] to provide a plaintext [mre] in the body of the question itself that demonstrates exactly what you expect the input/output relationship to be.  A playground link is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice (we can't require people navigate to another site to see your question code), and the particular example should ideally fit on a screen of normal-sized text all at once (or else it is probably not minimal).

Comment: Thank you, I've updated to add a minimal reproduction to the end of my question. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Is `data` doing anything in your example?  If not could you remove it?  The hope is that every piece of your example helps demonstrate the problem, not distract from it.

Comment: Updated to remove some of the noise.

Comment: And is there a point two having two functions, `send()` and `thisWouldBeReturnedFromWebWorker()`?  Do you need help with that? Or can you just provide `thisWouldBeReturnedFromWebWorker()` and name it `send()` for the sake of this example?

Comment: Like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9VMjm) should be what you want from the typings, although the compiler isn't smart enough to validate the implementation properly without type annotations like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMj2zW) or without fairly significant refactoring like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6VoGw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, your examples have helped me get something working.

Comment: So should I write up an answer explaining?  I will assume so.

Comment: Yes that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I'd take would be to represent the call signature to `send()` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that operates on the type parameter `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Action`, corresponding to the `action` property of the `payload` parameter:

```
declare function send<K extends Action>(payload: Message<K>): Promise<Return<K>>;
```

So the input type is `Message<K>` and the output type is `Promise<Return<K>>`.  We have to define `Message<K>` and `Return<K>`.  First let's do `Message<K>`:

```
type Message<K extends Action> =
    { [P in K]: { action: P } }[K]
```

This is a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), meaning it's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  The idea is that we want `Message<Action.Init>` to be `{action: Action.Init}`, and we want `Message<Action.Ack>` to be `{action: Action.Ack}`, and we want `Message<Action.Init | Action.Ack>` to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Message<Action.Init> | Message<Action.Ack>`.  That is, the operation *distributes* over unions in the input.

`Return<K>` is just a little more complex because we look up the `result` property in a helper interface:

```
interface ReturnMap {
    [Action.Init]: { somePropertiesHere: boolean };
    [Action.Ack]: { isSuccess: boolean }
}

type Return<K extends Action> = { [P in K]:
    { action: K, result: ReturnMap[K] }
}[K];
```

But it's basically the same idea.  Note that currently `Message<K>` is a bit complicated for what it does, but if you decide that a `Message<K>` should have other properties that depend on `K`, you can add them with something like a `MessageMap` interface, similarly to how `ReturnMap` is being used.

---

Given that call signature, you can now see that calls to `send()` work as you desire:

```
send({ action: Action.Init }).then(response => {
    response.result
    //       ^?(property) result: { somePropertiesHere: boolean; }
});
send({ action: Action.Ack }).then(response => {
    response.result
    //       ^?(property) result: { isSuccess: boolean; }
});
```

---

Unfortunately inside the implementation of `send()` you'll see that the compiler can't see that the specific return values are of the proper generic type:

```
async function send<K extends Action>(payload: Message<K>): Promise<Return<K>> {
    if (payload.action === Action.Init) {
        return { // error! Type 'Action.Init' is not assignable to type 'K'.
            action: Action.Init,
            result: {
                somePropertiesHere: true
            }
        };
    }

    return { action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } } // error!
    //     Type 'Action.Ack' is not assignable to type 'K'.
}
```

This is currently a limitation of TypeScript; checking a *value* of a generic type `K` doesn't affect the *type parameter* itself. The type of the value `payload.action` can be [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) from `K` to `Action.Init`, but `K` stubbornly stays the same. It doesn't get re-constrained to `Action.Init` or anything like it.  So the compiler cannot be sure that `{action: Action.Init, result: {somePropertiesHere: true}}` is actually a `Return<K>`.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) asking for improvement here, but for now it's not part of the language and you have to work around it.

---

By far the easiest workaround is just to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that you are returning appropriate values:

```
async function send<K extends Action>(payload: Message<K>): Promise<Return<K>> {
    if (payload.action === Action.Init) {
        return {
            action: Action.Init,
            result: {
                somePropertiesHere: true
            }
        } as Return<K>;
    }
    return { action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } } as Return<K>
}
```

This compiles cleanly because you're just saying "trust me, this return value is of type `Return<K>`".  But it would also compiler without error if you made a mistake in your check like `(payload.action !== Action.Init)` instead of `(payload.action === Action.Init)`:

```
async function badSend<K extends Action>(payload: Message<K>): Promise<Return<K>> {
    if (payload.action !== Action.Init) {
        return {
            action: Action.Init,
            result: {
                somePropertiesHere: true
            }
        } as Return<K>;
    }
    return { action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } } as Return<K>
}
```

When using type assertions, you should always be careful to ensure that what you are asserting is actually true.

---

Another workaround involves completing the refactoring to include the implementation and not just the types.  The GitHub issue microsoft/TypeScript#47109 that coined "distributive object type" did so as a way to allow the sort of input-output type relationship to be implemented.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const ioFuncs: { [P in Action]: (i: Message<P>) => Return<P> } = {
    init: (payload) => ({ action: Action.Init, result: { somePropertiesHere: true } }),
    ack: (payload) => ({ action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } });
}

async function send<K extends Action>(payload: Message<K>): Promise<Return<K>> {
    return ioFuncs[payload.action](payload);
}
```

The `ioFuncs` value is of a mapped type over `P in Action` that is explicitly written in terms of `Message<P>` and `Return<P>`.  And the implementation of `send()` involves looking up the appropriate property of `ioFuncs` and then calling it with `payload`.  That type checks because `ioFuncs[payload.action]` is seen by the type checker as being of the single type `(i: Message<P>) => Return<P>`. And since `payload` is of type `Message<P>`, the function returns `Return<P>`.

This is more involved than just using a type assertion, but it catches errors the assertions wouldn't.  If you made a mistake and swapped the `init` and `ack` property values, the compiler would notice and complain:

```
const badIoFuncs: { [P in Action]: (i: Message<P>) => Return<P> } = {
    ack: (payload) => ({ action: Action.Init, result: { somePropertiesHere: true } }), 
    init: (payload) => ({ action: Action.Ack, result: { isSuccess: true } });
} // errors!
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4Cgq9nAaygF4oByAQ0LIBoc8BJEJBE8pZhMrAXyywQBPAA7AoAWWABnKRQDmwADwBpKMAAeCUABMp+ZGgB8JergxQA2gAUoHKMoC6ALkxQqBkC5s8oPC4-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-6opKq7rnAm4Eh4O7aHuFJUoqx6fqerISBeChXnyc4CneD5PtxTZIG+H5fiyv7boBQEacqYFSZWMQqeBskZh46mZMqbE9ZBtZcd1w24HxIZekJEYiUZJntQpS2+B5GydaK4oMTJHEbTBvW3NmAxDNpo26X2BmDmJEmrT4q7rdBV6pIpcVrhueLJUS9QsuMpKqOS+xHdldV5eysiFdyxUhoKJL3ntFXjXg1Xvie34NSliGAUdIEsG1snKfElXDWp2ODStppnUTE2TQU-FtuGkaicZEnk2OK13Xo5XcvJJo7U6BP7STwEnb6zzdq4en9oZ12mat91c4Yz2pKm2jpkLLWcPm6paiAOrTuahpUxTYLmjWYs2i+tkmi2wgCe2naU4GtPTYJwlRlAjQxu08Z8-mPMq2rmb9f0mla4WutVmIZZGx1JslhanE2Y6To23b3qi-6EsXQOcwewssY+89PKAvwimhdOELROEiAoMEKSpHA+qsKgABiW65ycNh2IquS0kg54coVVi8ob5XD6tpCI7gHAsC4tW5T60eB31pOsRn4tO8GaezYzC03WZPJDU6VAEHPqMsovxjL4dwuEKd5vnfpOd77L47BQ3TceyyDAoG3BId5YLu6Ae5z37vlQeShh6Xwep8RQ48fCTwYifM+OVvzQOvvKVeLB76Z03nTGabsmYmVuofBiM8uLzzQYbDBzEnJ33XmNXsT9pbM1fsXZ6UALIISkNZVI8V3pbhSirdKgMsqULPOA8GXJrwlVvLDBWz5drQVsL-duFhz4-iYg4cR2h2Hv0lAHWUK8WIsDDjrPWcdSyKP5vreOZtrRJybKnemHYGE9imtvQhQ4C6jlwG-FM0ojE3zoUQVU2siy2KsTHEaliE6jUcSnd0tsXEOwflnZhV1PbDkLomdhPAgA)